# Simplifying a fraction?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

$$\frac {n-2}{n} \cdot \frac {n-3}{n-1} \cdot \frac {n-4}{n-2}  \cdots  \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac {1}{n(n-1)}$$

Why is this true? Notice the denominators and numerators cancel out, but since they "aren't in sync" the first  two denominators and the last two numerators will not be cancelled out. Considering this, shouldn't the product be:

$$\frac{2}{n(n-1)}$$

**What am I misunderstanding?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be $$\dfrac2{n(n-1)}$$
To see this take $n = 4$, we then get that $$\dfrac24 \cdot \dfrac13 = \dfrac{2}{4(4-1)}$$

Comment: So it's not just a misunderstanding, the book *is* wrong, correct?

Comment: @Riddler Yes, unless you have copied something wrong.

Comment: I double checked it -I guess it's an error . Thanks for the help Marvis!